# Notating Sample Space of X, Y

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I need to show the sample space for the following:
$$0 < x < 1$$

and

$$-1 < y < 1$$

On a graph, the area would look like the area shared in red. Is this correct? If so, how would I express the sample space in mathematical notation? I'm told it's the total area anywhere either x or y can occur.

[image: Graph of X and Y area]

I haven't been able to find any concrete examples of such notation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: Using interval notation, you can write this as $(0,1)\times(-1,1)$ or $]0,1[\, \times\,]-1,1[$ depending on how you show open intervals